# Yii foreign key

Tags: mysql, yii, foreign-keys

I have two tables with a 1 to many relationship setup in MySQL. I have used Gii to generate the models & CRUD.

Does Yii by default create a rule & default error message if I try enter a foreign key value that is in fact NOT a foreign key of the other table?

I came across this paragraph in 'The Yii Book', which may answer my question.

> "{TIP} The relationships are also needed by the 'exists' validator
>   which confirms that a foreign key value in this table exists as a
>   primary key in another."

So do I need to write an 'exists' validator?

Comment: CExistValidator validates that the attribute value exists in a table.

Comment: Ahh, k. So something like this?
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8085-problem-with-cexistvalidator/

I thought that Yii would handle those types of errors since I set up the relations in the database b4 using Gii to generate the models and CRUD. In the past I have always used a dropdown with the foreign key as the value, and not noticed the possibility of seeing the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No validation rule related to the foreign key is created by default.

Yii will generate an error message (CDbException) if the database gives a foreign key violation error though.

Comment: When you say no validation rules are created by default. Do you mean in the function rules() in the model? because that picks up rules, like if I specify in MYSQL that a field is required. it has.
    array('user_id, nick_name', 'required'),
for example.
But if I try create a record and the foreign key doesnt match an existing one in the DB, it throws an ugly error message

CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. If the field is created NOT NULL you will get a "required" rule, but never a rule related to the fk. That means validation will pass and you get a cdbexception because of the constraint violation.

Comment: Ahh, k. Thank you. That answers my question. MT!

Comment: Although doesn't it seem like a good thing for Yii to take care of nicely out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Yii Creats its default rules that you could find in the model for example

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('primaryEmail, password, creationTime, IPAddress, isBusiness, forgotPassTime, aboutMe, fname, lname', 'required'),

        );
    }
```

You could also provide a custom message for the validation

And it also provides its default relations for example

```
public function relations()
    {
return array(
            'articles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Article', 'authorId'),
}
```